# Access Lookup Wizard multivalues

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have table which have 3 columns: ID, NameOfProduct, Type and than I have created a form which has column in which I used Lookup Wizard so the user can choose from the list which product he wants (in the choice list there are two columns: NameOfProduct and Type - this is correct). But when I click on one row in this choice list it only imports one column : NameOfProduct, and I want to import Type as well. How can I do this? Is this something I can do in Lookup Wizard or do I have to maybe connect Type in this form to NameOfProduct?

Comment: First, advise not to build lookup field in table. Just build combobox or listbox on form. Why do you want to replicate Type value into another table? This violates db normalization. If you do want to save, that requires code (macro or VBA).

Comment: Actually, NameOfProduct should not be 'imported', actual value of field should be ID. Retrieve related data in query that joins tables. Type is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names.